# Remove Paperclip Attachment from Nested Attribute (Cocoon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, cocoon-gem

I have an INCIDENT with an attached WITNESS.

I am trying to show a link to remove an attachment from a nested attribute, but my link is pulling the :id of the parent record (invoice.id) instead of the nested/child record (invoice.witness_id).

I know I'm doing something wrong in my routes or in calling the correct id number from the controller or view... any help is appreciated!

**incident.rb**

```
  has_many :witnesses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :witnesses, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

**witness.rb**

```
  belongs_to :incident  
  has_attached_file :statement
```

**routes.rb**

```
match 'witness/:id' => 'witnesses#remove_statement', via: [:get, :post], as: 'remove_statement'
```

**witnesses_controller**

```
  def index
    @witnesses = @incident.witnesses.all
  end

  def remove_statement
    @witness = Witness.find(params[:id])
    @witness.statement = nil
    respond_to do |format|
        if @witness.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Attachment was removed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back, error: 'Attachment could not be removed.'  }
          format.json { render json: @witness.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
     end

  private
    def set_witness
      @witness = @incident.witnesses.find(params[:id])
    end

    def witness_params
      params[:witness].permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :statement, :incident_id)
    end
```

**_witness_fields partial**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
    ....
    <%= link_to "Remove Attachment", remove_statement_path, :id => :witness_id  %>
    ...
```

**incidents/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@incident, html: { :multipart => true , class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <% if @incident.errors.any? %>
    <div class="red">
      <% @incident.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <%= msg %><hr>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
.....

<!-- WITNESS SECTION -->
<div class="span6">
<hr>
    <fieldset id="witnesses">
        <%= f.fields_for :witnesses do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'witness_fields', :f => builder %>
        <% end %>    
    </fieldset>
    <p class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Witness/Contact', f, :witnesses, { class:"btn btn-primary" } %>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END WITNESSES SECTION -->
.....
```

Comment: Just want to add that I wish more SO questions were characterized as witnessed incidents.  Useful question and answer.  Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_withness_fields` partial, you write

```
<%= link_to "Remove Attachment", remove_statement_path, :id => :witness_id  %>
```

That should be something like

```
<%= link_to "Remove Attachment", remove_statement_path(f.object.id)  %>
```

So two things: the path helper `remove_statement_path` needs the `id` as a parameter, and secondly, you need to actually give it the correct id of the object for which you are currently rendering.

Please note, since you dynamically add these, for new records this will not be valid (since there is no idea).

So you will have to check if the record is a `new_record?` and only show that link if it is not (because then you will have a valid id). If it is not a new record, you can just use the cocoon helper to remove it.

Comment: Thank you - I tried `:id => f.object.id` before, but that didn't work. I guess I need to brush up on syntax.  This is working now - I was so close!  And, yes, I already have a check in place for existing records only.  I don't even show the Remove Link unless one exists.  Thanks again!!